# [Kinect]About camera calibration

Tags: ros, calibration, kinect, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I just want to calibrate the camera, but i get this message:

```
rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 5x4 --square 0.0245 image:=/camera/image_raw camera:=/camera
('Waiting for service', '/camera/set_camera_info', '...')
Service not found
```

Already ran:

```
roscore
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
```

What generates this error?

Thanks beforehand!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204129/%5Bkinect%5Dabout-camera-calibration/) by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) on ROS Answers with karma: 82 on 2015-03-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have weird topics names for openni_launch. Shouldn't you have something like image:=/camera/rgb/image_raw and camera:=/camera/rgb (replace rgb by ir if you want to calibrate the deptch camera).

When you run `rosservice list` do you have services beginning by /camera/ ?

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2015-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0